# What stat should I increase to not get knocked down from body checks so easily in "Be a Pro"?

Tags: nhl-13

In the beginning of the season I was able to line up shots and score a lot. However, once opponents realized that my player was a threat they have a guy stuck to me and knocking me down every time I take a shot. Is there a stat that I should focus on to be able to take body checks without going down every time? I've increased strength a lot but I still can't fight through these checks and it's getting annoying that I have to take fast, inaccurate shots every time I shoot at the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer on [HERE](http://nhlguides.net/player-attributes/) and decided to post it for future reference:

> **Strength**: This attribute is a modifier that affects shot power, fighting, checking, **resisting hits**, and boardplay. Strength will give extra power in shots, punches and hitting. Strength will also help with resisting hits. Strength affects the ability to pin players to the boards while initiating boardplay, and the ability to slip free when one is being pinned in boardplay.

So, focusing even more on Strength is the way to go. Should be true for all versions of NHL, not just the tagged.